# Sony Vegas 17 can't render a 1:1 video?

Tags: vegas-pro, render

I have a video that I want to render as a 1:1 (1920x1920) aspect ratio. But it seems sony vegas 17 won't render it. And it gives me this error:

[image]

***Here's my video properties:***

[image]

***And here's the render settings:***

[image]

[image]

I've tried resetting sony vegas, try restarting my computer and etc. I've even tried to change my setting on by one, and it seems the only problem is the resolution. Whenever I tried to change the resolution/aspect ratio to 16:9 its fixed, but when I turn it to 1:1 it gives me the error. I need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, why this is happening, but I could reproduce this issue and get it fixed by using a "Magix AVC/AAC MP4" codec instead of the Sony codec.